# Issue with Regular Expression for Input Validation

Tags: c#, regex

I have this requirement to check for characters, numbers, and few special characters from a given user input. The input can have A-Z, a-z, 0-9,.,?, and >. It shouldn’t have any other special character.

If the input has one it should stop there and do some other staff. I was trying to write the regular expression like this (below) but it keeps giving always false - I don't know what I am missing:

```
string[] vals = allParams.Split(':');
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9?>.]$");
foreach (string value in vals)
{
    string result = rgx.IsMatch(value).ToString();
    if (result == "False")
        return;
}
```

Comment: Converting a `bool` to a `string` just to compare with another `string` really blows my mind off.

Comment: Agreed with Uwe. Original poster: you can combine lines 5 and 6 into this: `if (!rgx.IsMatch(value))`

Comment: also keep in mind that if you do not want to use RegEx you could also use the Char. methods as well just an FYI

Comment: Why do you split the incoming text? One could create a regex which will look through all the params at once, ignoring the ':' and validating all parameters and returning a true or false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex posted:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9?>.]$"
```

Matches a *single* character between the start and end of the string.

The following will search for one or more of these characters:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9?>.]+$"
```

---

Note - regarding your roundtripping of a bool. This is a better way of doing it:

```
bool result = rgx.IsMatch(value);
if (!result)
    return;
```

Or, even shorter:

```
if(!rgx.IsMatch(value))
   return;
```

Comment: @ean5533 - Thanks. By all means, feel free to correct such typos yourself.

Comment: Even shorter: Don't bother creating a regex instance, call the static (which will cache the pattern automatically)

Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9?>.]+$")